# Insert into SQL Server table gives me nothing

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

Very frustrating one... I have tried many combinations of ', " and so on but my insert command just refreshing the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Simple two text fields form with button. Under button I have this:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["przychodniaConnectionString1"].ConnectionString);
con.Open();

string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO specyfik(speNazwa, speIlosc) values ('" + speNazwa.Text + "', '" + speIlosc.Text + "')";
SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con);
con.Close();
```

Zero errors while compiling and when testing, it seems like refreshed page. Nothing appears in db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't you need to call `insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` ?

```
...
SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con); 
int row_affected = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
...
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to execute your SqlCommand:

```
insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, you should look into parameterizing that query:
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: I need some way to +1 again the parameterizing sentence.

Comment: Thank you! A habbit from php I guess, because I thought that SqlCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, con); will do a job ;)

Answer (score 0):

Will you like to make more improvements in your code using stored Proc and improvemnet in your code behind file ? Take a look at this answer...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595501/1209450