# How to check if value from a cell in a column is !=NULL?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying on gridview updated to check if a cell from a certain column is != NULL ( to check if the user wrote something into the cell)

My problem is I don't know how to get the "x column" value from cell.

Comment: What db framework are you using? Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, ADO.Net?

Answer (score 1):

inzi irina Please look at this code. don't forget to vote me if this helps you

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dr in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            string lngth = Convert.ToString(dr.Cells[1].Value);
            if (lngth.Length > 0)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(dr.Cells[0].Value);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are approaching through following ways...

> 1. You have a footer template and may have a button which saves the values from your footer.
> 2. You have an Edit/Update button in grid for each row

---

### For Approach 1(i.e. Footer Template)

You can find like below...

```
TextBox testing = (TextBox)grd.FooterRow.FindControl("Your Control ID");
```

---

### For Approach 2 (i.e. using Edit/Update Button)

You can do like below..

**Sample Code Behind**

```
protected void grd_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox testing = (TextBox)grd.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Your Control ID");
}
```

---

**Sample HTML**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd" runat="server" onrowupdating="grd_RowUpdating">
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: It didn't worked , I just want to get the value from a cell on row updateD

Comment: you should have a grd_RowUpdating event handler. This will make your life very easy.

Comment: yea but , control id =? id of the column?

Comment: id of the textbox control in that template

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8834/discussion-between-pankaj-garg-and-inzi-irina)

Comment: I can't write in chat I don't know why

Comment: There's just a simple gridview  ,and on row updating  " protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox testing = (TextBox)GridView1..Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Name");
}
where Name = column name .

Comment: Seems like you need to change the approach. Take a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/9595501/1209450