# Gridview , on row update get the value from a cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

- I have a simple gridview.
- 3 Columns |

  ```
  NAME AGE Birthday
  ```

On **RowUpdated** I want to get something like:

```
  Gridview1.Column[2].Cell[2].Text
```

so I can get the value from the column 2. How can I do it?

Thank you.
pS: row updated & row updating are the same thing?

Comment: You know that [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx) is a good source for questions like _"row updated & row updating are the same thing?"_ ?!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687589/how-to-check-if-value-from-a-cell-in-a-column-is-null

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the MSDN article with example code: [GridView.RowUpdating Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdating.aspx#Y342)

Row **updated** and updating are not the same.  Updating happens ***before*** the GridView control updates the row and **updated** is *after* the data has been updated.

In your Gridview control you need to add `OnRowUpdating="TaskGridView_RowUpdating"`

Assuming the value is in a textbox in the Age column this is how you would store the value in a string:

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
  {    
    GridViewRow row = TaskGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    String str = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;
  }
```

Comment: this is it right ?     dt.Rows[row.DataItemIndex]["Id"] = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[1].Controls[0])).Text;

Comment: @InziIrina - The example takes the value of the textbox control and adds it to a datatable.

Comment: tried for so many days and still couldn't find a way, I've tried all examples I found and I couldn't find a way to get on update the value of a cell from.

Comment: @InziIrina - Every time I shake my magic 8 ball it keeps responding with "Outlook not so good"

Answer (score 1):

If you have data directly in the GridView cell (no label or textbox, etc) then this worked for me

```
protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender,    
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs e )
   {
   int row;
   int colidx =1;
   string cellvalue;

   GridViewRow row = Gridview1.rows[e.rowindex]
   cellvalue = row.cells[colidx].text;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Gridview1.Rows[Gridview1.EditIndex].Cells[2].Text.ToString();
```