# How do I create a new database on SQL Server in a unique new name?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008r2-express

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET with C# on .NET 4.0 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I would like to create a database on the server named `WINSRV\SQLSRV`.

How do I loop to test for a unique database name?

My default database should be `ab`. In case this name is taken, I would like to create a database named `ab1`, and if this one is also taken - `ab2` and so forth.

**I need it to rum from a web page created in the Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET C# script, and not from the SQL server management studio.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @Iteration int
Set @Iteration = 0
Declare @DBName varchar(100)

while(@Iteration <> -1)
begin
    if(@Iteration = 0)
        Set @DBName = 'ab'
    Else
        Set @DBName = 'ab' + Convert(varchar, @Iteration)
    IF NOT EXISTS(select Object_Id from sys.databases where name = 'ab')
    Begin

        Exec('create database ' +  @DBName)
        return;
    End
    Else
    Begin
        Set @Iteration = @Iteration + 1
    End
End
```

**Edit**

To Work from C# click **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9595501/1209450)**

Comment: It does not work! To fix it I made this correction:
IF NOT EXISTS(select name from sys.databases where name = @DBName)
Now, this is not the C# I need, and this is a huge part of the problem. Where should I open a connection? Should I use transact? Wouldn't it be better to use try/catch? Therefore, I found nothing helpful in the link attached. Any directions? thanks. BTW, is there an automatic translator from T-SQL to C#?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to check to see if your choices for databases exist:

You can do it primary sql side as so:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases WHERE name = 'ab')))
    --Do what you need to do
```

or you could get a list databases and check .net side:

```
SELECT name FROM master.sys.databases
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please use `sys.databases` - `sysdatabases` is only there for backward compatibility.